# Is there an alternative for position: 'sticky in react-native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I'm trying to make an element stay at the top of the screen at all times, vene when scrolling. I found out that `position: 'sticky'` does this for regular html. I was wondering if there was something I could add to my css to make the element stick to one place while scrolling using react-native.

Answer (score 4):

On `ScrollView` there is a prop called [stickyHeaderIndices](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#stickyheaderindices). Pass the index of the component that you want to be sticky in this prop. For example, if you want to sticky the header to be sticky from the below code, you have to just pass 1 in `stickyHeaderIndices` props like this :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.overline}>
          Overline
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.header}>
          Header
        </Text>
      </View>
      {/* Your others component goes here */}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overline: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '100'
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  spacer: {
    height: 10,
  }
});

export default App;
```

This prop accepts the array, so you can also set multiple sticky components by passing the index of those all components.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `ScrollView`'s `stickyHeaderIndices` didn't work for my use-case, where I had an element that wasn't full-screen. (It stretched the element out to full screen; when I tried to wrap it in a `View`, it stopped being sticky.)

What worked for me was simply putting the element I wished to be sticky *before* the `ScrollView`, rather than inside it, and applying absolute positioning. A similar approach also worked for me for a sticky footer.

```js
<MyComponent style={{position: absolute;}}/> // will be sticky to top
<ScrollView> 
    // scrolling components
</ScrollView>
<OtherComponent /> // functionally sticky to bottom; looks like content is scrolling behind it, even though the scrollview just stops before it.
```